# Why do I get exit code 1 after yarn installs without any message?

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg

I have a project, production. It used to work, today after entering `yarn installs` the project starts rebuild, and I get:

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[0] yarn install && yarn build exited with code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried deleting node_modules or running yarn cache or yarn upgrade, but all to no avail. not even a message on what the error is. Framework: Nextjs